# how to create OSLC docs using Jena?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I need to create RDF/XML documents containing objects in the OSLC namespace. 
e.g.

```
<oslc_disc:ServiceProviderCatalog
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"  
    xmlns:oslc_disc="http://open-services.net/xmlns/discovery/1.0/"
 rdf:about="{self}">

  <dc:title>{catalog title}</dc:title>
  <oslc_disc:details rdf:resource="{catalog details uri}" />
```

what is the simplest way to create this doc using the Jena API ?
( I know about Lyo, they use a JSP for this doc :-)

Thanks, Carsten

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example to start you off. Be aware that this will be *equivalent* to XML output you want, but may not be identical. The order of properties, for example, may vary, and there are other ways to write the same content.

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.DCTerms;

public class Jena {

    // Vocab items -- could use schemagen to generate a class for this
    final static String OSLC_DISC_NS = "http://open-services.net/xmlns/discovery/1.0/";
    final static Resource ServiceProviderCatalog = 
        ResourceFactory.createResource(OSLC_DISC_NS + "ServiceProviderCatalog");
    final static Property details = 
        ResourceFactory.createProperty(OSLC_DISC_NS, "details");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Inputs
        String selfURI = "http://example.com/self";
        String catalogTitle = "Catalog title";
        String catalogDetailsURI = "http://example.com/catalogDetailsURI";

        // Create in memory model
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        // Set prefixes
        model.setNsPrefix("dc", DCTerms.NS);
        model.setNsPrefix("oslc_disc", OSLC_DISC_NS);

        // Add item of type spcatalog
        Resource self = model.createResource(selfURI, ServiceProviderCatalog);
        // Add the title
        self.addProperty(DCTerms.title, catalogTitle);
        // Add details, which points to a resource
        self.addProperty(details, model.createResource(catalogDetailsURI));

        // Write pretty RDF/XML
        model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
    }

}
```